# Equation with variable $λ$ that should be $R$ for $x$

Tags: functional-equations

I need to find for $λ\in R$ the domain of 
$f(x)=\sqrt{((λ-2)x^2-2λx+2λ-3)}$

It should be $λ\in[6,+∞ )$ as per my book but I dont understand why.
Sorry for my english

Comment: consider $h(x)=(\lambda-2)x^2-2\lambda x+2\lambda-3$ and compute $h'(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of the $f(x)$ is the set of values of $x$ which satisfy the following inequation:
$$(λ-2)x^2-2λx+2λ-3\gt0\tag{i}$$
For the domain to be the set of real numbers, (i) must hold for any real $x$.
Since the expression is a quadratic in $x$, we know that it will be always positive if its discriminant is non-positive, and the leading coefficient positive. This gives us the following conditions on $\lambda$:-
$$\lambda-2\gt 0\tag{ii}$$
$$4\lambda^2-4(2\lambda-3)(\lambda-2)\le 0\tag{iii}$$
Solving (ii) and (iii) the asnwer will be $\lambda\in[6,\infty)$